# Spring NON MVC project configuration - Best Practices

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

I am going to work on a Java project and want to use Spring IOC for bean management.

This is not a web project but just a simple java project that will give me a jar file at the end.

My questions is that, in my application i want to use Spring IoC to get instances of classes to call their respective methods. For the purpose i need to get the spring context using

```
CalenderDao calenderDao = (CalenderDao) ApplicationContextUtils
                .getApplicationContext().getBean("calenderDao");
        calenderDao.getCalenderUpdate();
```

Now if i need this bean in some other class too , i will copy and paste the same thing there as well like.

```
CalenderDao calenderDao = (CalenderDao) ApplicationContextUtils
                .getApplicationContext().getBean("calenderDao");
        calenderDao.getCalenderUpdate();
```

My question here is that, do i need to create a ApplicationContext in each file to get a bean throughout the application. Or is there any alternate and best thing to perform. And if i am doing the thing like this way how can use setter injection or constructor injection in application.

In web apps this is quit simple we loads the context one time and everything works fine, but how to do this in non web where we don't have web.xml file to instantiate the context.

Please help how beans are managed in non web project using spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is not just designed for web apps.

Just because it's not a web application you dont need to fall back to "provider style". You do not need a web.xml to initialize an application context.

Use your main method to create an application context and work with your beans as you would do for a webapp. You can use autowiring and all the gadgets of spring.

Once the context is initialized call your main class to start your application, for example with the help of the refresh event. From there on you have (almost) no need to use getBean.

Obviously you dont have session and request scope, but singleton and prototype are available.

Just take a look at the spring docs.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you require ApplicationContext in your application, implement that class with `ApplicationContextAware` interface.

Say here

```
 public class CalenderService implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext context;//declare this so you can use it

 }
```

As it is interface you need to overide its method

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context){
   this.context=context; // here ApplicationContext gets injected.
}
```